# Switching long inheritance tree for composition / agreggation

Tags: oop, design-patterns, polymorphism, aggregation, decoupling

I have a program in Java which uses a lot of inheritance, and it's making it troublesome to modify and test the final derived classes

So I'm refactoring, attempting to switch from inheritance to aggregation / composition. The design in question is similar to `A isInheritedBy -> B isInheritedBy -> C isInheritedBy -> D`

My problems are:

- Calling functions from derived classes instances that the base classes don't have, while still having access to the base classes functions. There is often a need to call things like `d.methodNotInBaseClasses()` that calls functions from the base classes
- Calling overridden functions through the derived class instances, so calling `d.methodFirstDefinedInA()` that can call the same method from instances of C, B and A
- I need to maintain polymorphic behavior to minimize the required changes to the rest of the code. Currently there is a lot of `A a = new D()`
- I need to have loose coupling between base and derived classes

The best design I've thought of for class creation is:

*Assume that classes A,B,C and D exist, where B to D are coupled to the previous class by constructor dependency injection*

```
class Builder {
    public A createInstanceOfA(){
        return new A();
    }

    public B createInstanceOfB(){
        return new B(createInstanceOfA());
    }

    public C createInstanceOfC(){
        return new C(createInstanceOfB());
    }

    public D createInstanceOfD(){
        return new D(createInstanceOfC());
    }
}
```

This seems fine for me. However for polymorphic behavior behavior from base classes I'm defining interfaces that each derived class implements for its base classes:

```
interface InterfaceForA {
    void doSomething();
}

interface InterfaceForB extends InterfaceForA {
    void doMore();
}

interface InterfaceForC extends InterfaceForB {
    void doEvenMore();
}

interface InterfaceForD extends InterfaceForC {
    void doTheMost();
}
```

And now you can see the problems of duplicated functions:

*Sidenote: I'm aware @Override is not required for interface implementations, I added those for clarity*

```
class A implements InterfaceForA {
    public void doSomething(){
        System.out.println("A did something");
    }
}

class B implements InterfaceForB {
    private A a;

    B(A a){
        this.a = a;
    }

    @Override
    public void doSomething(){
        a.doSomething();
    }

    public void doMore(){
        a.doSomething();
        System.out.println("B did more");
    }
}

class C implements InterfaceForC {
    private B b;

    C(B b){
        this.b = b;
    }

    @Override
    public void doSomething(){
        b.doSomething();
    }

    @Override
    public void doMore(){
        b.doMore();
    }

    public void doEvenMore(){
        b.doMore();
        System.out.println("C did even more");
    }
}

class D implements InterfaceForD {
    private C c;

    D(C c){
        this.c = c;
    }

    @Override
    public void doSomething(){
        c.doSomething();
        System.out.println("D did something");
    }

    @Override
    public void doMore(){
        c.doMore();
    }

    @Override
    public void doEvenMore(){
        c.doEvenMore();
    }

    public void doTheMost(){
        c.doEvenMore();
        System.out.println("D did the most");
    }
}
```

All for being able to do these:

```
class App {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Builder builder = new Builder();
        D d = builder.createInstanceOfD();

        // Allows functions the base classes don't have, yet have access to the base classes functions
        d.doTheMost();
        System.out.println("---");

        // Allows calling overriden functions of the base classes directly
        d.doSomething();
        System.out.println("---");

        // Allows calling overriden function from base classes interfaces
        InterfaceForA a = d;
        a.doSomething();
    }
}
```

If this already seems too complex, consider also that the entire dependency tree consists of about 90 classes, with the deepest ones maybe with 6-8 base classes

I also tried the Strategy pattern, with dependencies inverted like `A dependsOn InterfaceForB, B dependsOn InterfaceForC, C dependsOn InterfaceForD` and D having no dependencies, but I couldn't wrap my head around it. I had to make Builder more complicated, I could only call A methods from D by making D depend on A, and to either:

- Keep references to the instance of each base class and call each instance function separatedly. The client code from the 13 lines in main() grew to 28
- Use getters in base clases to get the interface to their strategy. The client code grew from 13 to 20, and the entire code grew from 129 to 148

Thoughts?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to replicate features of inheritance without using inheritance proper. What exactly makes this design less susceptible to your original troubles than a plain old inheritance-based design?

Comment: I believe you're correct. I looked around a lot before posting here but almost all online sources focus on maintaining hierarchical program architecture with composition. I've decided that changing the design is unavoidable if I want code that's easy to understand

Comment: I now get that you can make the same mistakes with composition as with inheritance, it's just harder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your understanding of *Composition* is wrong. Unless you want to implement something like the *Facade* pattern you don't want to mimic all the types that a type is composed of.

Just rewind the reel: the general idea is to reuse functionality that some type has already implemented.

One solution is to use inheritance. Inheritance has some drawbacks (e.g. limited extensibility/testability or the fact that multi-inheritance is usually not supported by OO languages - for good reasons).
A second solution is to implement interfaces. The drawback is that you have to reimplement every functionality. Whle this solution enables polymorphism it does not help much when the goal is to reuse existing features.
A third and most famous solution is to use *Composition*/*Aggregation* in order to get access to the functionality of those other types.

*Composition* is also perceived as the more natural class design that helps to avoid design mistakes. For example a `House` should not inherit from `Basement`, `Stairway` and `Attic` to provide the required features.
Instead a house (`House`) is usually build (composed) of a `Basement`, `Stairway` and an `Attic` - that enables a more intuitive class design and usage.
This example makes it also clear why the composed type should not implement all the interfaces that define the owned types (like in your original example): because a house *is not* a basement. A house *is not* a stairway. And a house *is not* an attic. A house is a complex entity composed of many components. Some of those components are even aggregated and can be reused once the house is destroyed.

The difference:
When using inheritance the subclass *owns* the inherited members. It can change the inherited behavior by overriding the virtual members.
When using *Composition*/*Aggregation* the class does not own any members and can't modify their behavior. Instead it owns a reference to the type that implements the required functionality and the access is restricted to the public class API (opposed to protected members when using inheritance).

To convert inheritance to composition is very simple:

- ensure the required functionality is available via public API.
- if not, you must extend the type to expose the required functionality. Then use the new subclass to compose your type.
- create the instances that the composed type requires in constructor (*Composition*) or request them as constructor parameters (*Aggregation*). Store those instances in private fields (i.e. hide them from the public API).

Example:

```java
class A {

  public void playVideo(Uri videoSource) {}
}
```

```java
class B {

  protected void playMusic(Uri musicSource) {}
}
```

```java
class C {
  
  public playWebResource(Url webResource) {}
}
```

We could now create a `MediaPlayer` type that extends `A`, `B` and `C`. Because we want to improve our class design and therefore avoid a terrible inheritance tree and other design flaws we decide to use *Composition*.

Now to make the protected `B.playMusic` available, we must extend `B`:

```java
class NewB extends B {

  public void playMusicSource(Uri musicSource) {

    playMusic(musicSource);
  }
}
```

Now compose the new type that is now extended with the functionality of `A`, `B` and `C`:

```java
class ComposedABC {

  private A a;
  private NewB b;
  private C c;

  public ComposedABC() {
    
    this.a = new A();
    this.b = new NewB();
    this.c = new C();
  }

  // Example of using the extended functionality
  public PlayMedia(MediaType mediaType, Uri mediaSource) {
   
    switch (mediaType) {
      case Video: this.a.playVideo(mediaSource); break;
      case Music: this.b.playMusicSource(mediaSource); break;
      case Web: this.c.playWebResource(mediaSource); break;
    }
  }
}
```

The key is that the internal types that the composition type is composed of are usually inaccessible for the public (private). The client of the composed type's API must not now what types are internally used to provide a functionality (information hiding). If you need to expose the functionality directly, always implement a public member and use delegation:

```java
class ComposedType {

  private SomeType someType;

  public ExecuteSomeTypeFunctionality() {

    // Delegate method call
    this.someType.SomeTypeFunctionality();
  }
}
```

Comment: Changing inheritance for composition is easy when there's not a deep hierarchy. I never found a source online that addressed that. I did find eventually a person asking on stack exchange [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/335383/arent-deep-composition-hierarchies-bad-too) if deeply hierarchical composition wasn't bad too, and that's when it clicked. Composition is better not just because of the looser coupling but because it flattens hierarchies, so I do have to redesign to move away from the deep hierarchies

Comment: The mere fact that the inheritance tree is deep is not the problem. It sometimes even makes sense. It becomes problematic when inheritance is used to reuse functionality where inheritance is semantically wrong. Usually such cases end up with a bloated API (functionality) where most public members (functionality) are not used/needed. It also creates semantic confusion, e.g. let a DataTable inherit from a List. The idea is not to replace inheritance, because inheritance is an important language feature. The idea is to know when inheritance is the wrong choice and composition is to be favored.

Comment: By the way, the "Liskov substitution principle (LSP)", the "L" in SOLID, is the more useful principle to follow in order to determine if inheritance makes sense. If you *have* to break LSP then you know that inheritance is the wrong choice. Instead use the class of interest to compose your type (in order to add the desired functionality). "Law of Demeter" is not useful in helping to decide what extension method to use. LoD is about decoupling and so called "information hiding". It's pretty useless in this context. I'm just replying to your provided link about deep inheritance hierarchies.

Comment: One last note. Inheritance has a very special purpose (which is quite well expressed in the terminology that the UML language uses). While both inheritance and composition are about extending functionality, inheritance is more specific. It's about specialization. You always start with a very general type (the superclass or base class). Every subclass must be a more specialized version of the superclass it extends. It must not change the complete behavior of the superclass (LSP principle). It just specializes.

Comment: *Naturally*, there is a certain depth, maybe max 5-8 levels, where there is no more specialization possible. For example an application framework has to hide (LoD) all the low-level OS details like input message handling. It does this by encapsulating those details in abstract classes and by defining related logic as private. You easily get 4 levels of inheritance before you actual implement the first framework high-level class that is used by the client.

Comment: Frameworks are a good example to understand that deep hierarchies can make sense and that LoD does not relate to inheritance or tree depth. However, at the point where there are no more vertical specializations possible you start to create siblings (horizontal specialization), specializations that all share the same superclass i.e. are on the same level in the hierarchy. When following this principle, you usually don't find yourself ending up with deep hierarchies. Same applies to composition. If the class design is clean you usually don't end up with deep hierarchies.

Comment: Important, *"deep hierarchy"* is a broad definition. The word *"deep"* is used very unspecific. The point is that there is a particular depth when you have to ask yourself if you lost track and e.g. have violated the LSP principle. If the answer is "yes", fix your design to avoid future issues. If "no" then leave the hierarchy as it is. Again, the depth is only a measure or indicator to help you to identify if you are currently misusing inheritance. The depth itself is not the problem. Like inheritance is not always the correct solution so is composition.

Comment: You have to learn about architecture and class design to understand when to use which. In fact your referenced link is a totally  wrong explanation because LoD is not violated when creating deep (or flat) inheritance trees.

Comment: @coz Maybe [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/446778/364764) helps to further understand the matter.